# SQL query based on select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the select option I have:

```
<div class="selectTeam" style="float:right;color:black;">
  <label for="teams">Choose Team:</label>
  <select name="teams" id="teams">
    <option value="both">Alle Teams</option>
    <option value="2">Team 2</option>
    <option value="3">Team 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is how mu query looks like.

```
$stmt = $link -> prepare('SELECT id, ident, pp, date FROM sales WHERE status=? team=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5');
$status = "OK";
$stmt -> bind_param("si", $status, $team);
```

I know I can use `document.getElementById("pplegal").value` in JS to get the selected value, but how can I do this in PHP, and run the query based on what is selected?

```
If option value 2 = team=2
If option value 3 = team=3
If option value both = team=2 and 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP the form parameters are in `$_POST`. You can check for the special case of `$team == 'both'` and put the list of teams in the SQL. Otherwise, use a parameter to substitute the variable into the query.

```
$team = $_POST['teams'];
$stats = 'OK';

if ($team == 'both') {
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT id, ident, pp, date FROM sales WHERE status=? AND team IN (2, 3) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $status);
} else {
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT id, ident, pp, date FROM sales WHERE status=? AND team=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5');
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $status, $team);
}
```

Comment: So `$_POST['teams'];` will be created when I change the option select value?

Comment: It's created when you submit the form. Read a tutorial on processing forms with PHP.

Comment: But I'm not going to submit a form? I just want to change the query when the selecting value from the option,

Comment: PHP is not running any more when the user is interacting with the page. You have to submit the form or use AJAX to run something on the server.

Comment: Or you could put the data for both teams in a JavaScript object, and then use JavaScript to display the relevant data when the user selects an option.